# Navigation issue when in an MVC area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-routing

I have a common navigation menu that I use throughout my mvc 5 application. The home link is defined as follows:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
       <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> 
       <span class="nav-label">Home</span> 
 </a>
```

The problem is when I navigate to my admin "area", such as to [root]**/admin/customers**, if I click on the'Home' link it tries to goto "**/admin/Home**", versus Home in the root.

**Question**: Do I have to create 2 different menus in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try to specify the area: `@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "" })`?

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly tell MVC to not use an any(*current*) area when building the result of `Url.Action` call.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home",new {area=string.Empty})">Home</a>
```

You can do the same thing when using the `Html.ActionLink` helper method as well.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Home",new {area=string.Empty},null)
```